# Overflowing bounty revision height in post revision history in Chrome (v63.0.3239.132) Windows 7

Tags: bug, revision-history

The top padding is set to 8 pixels of bounty [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39504805/revisions).

Which cause the height overflow from other cell.

[image]

---

**Browser:** Chrome - Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) 
**OS:** Windows 7 Pro 64-bit

Comment: No repro in Firefox 57.0.4 Windows [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DUbl.png) or chrome latest stable in windows

Comment: I see the same padding, yet cannot repro either. It's a table, applying padding to a cell should normally not cause it to overflow the table row.